# How can I customize a template for custom Woocommerce fields?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

I created some fields with Advanced Custom Fields for the woocommerce orders. I want to custom the template orders.php to show the ACF fields in the orders table. These fields includ images. I found no plugin or hook to do this for the orders users page.

This hook below shows how to add a button to orders action. What I need is add a column to show a custom field.

```
function sv_add_my_account_order_actions( $actions, $order ) {

    $actions['help'] = array(
        // adjust URL as needed
        'url'  => '/contact/?&order=' . $order->get_order_number(),
        'name' => __( 'Get Help', 'my-textdomain' ),
    );

    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'sv_add_my_account_order_actions', 10, 2 );
```

Thanks!

Comment: SO is a coding network, and as such you must provide some as a starting point. For more general questions you might try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @isherwood wordpress.stackexchange.com **is exclusively for pure wordpress** So NO plugins as woocommerce and ACF as they are off-topic.